# How to set up a Google Sheet to automatically create new tabs/sheets for Google Form responses based on the date?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

Our company is trying to find a way to set up a Google spreadsheet to automatically create new tabs/sheets for Google Form responses that come in based on the date. Theoretically, with submissions coming in every day this would categorize them into tabs named the date. For example, if I submit a form response on 11/29 and it goes to that sheet, we would like for it to be able to automatically create a new sheet/tab called 11/29 or something and then automatically add that entry into that sheet. This way all entries are all automatically categorized by the day. It is my understanding that this could be done with scripting, but I am uneducated in that area and am unsure how to proceed with this. Any help would be absolutely appreciated.

I found this script which appears to sort of do part of what we want (minus the deleting stuff), but was unsuccessful in getting it to work properly (likely ignorance on my end). Can this be adjusted to only add the new tabs named by the date? Apologies for the ignorance, this scripting stuff is new to me.

```
    function createDeleteTabs() {
  
    /*  DASHBOARD---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Edit this section to change the dates tabs are created for and the range of data that will be cleared each time! */
  
    var numberOfDaysForwardForNextTab = 17
    var numberOfDaysBackwardForDeleteTab = 53
    var rangeToClear = 'F5:CS'
  
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   // get the spreadsheet object
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]); // set the first sheet as active

    // Sets date for add tab & date for delete tab
    var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var today = new Date();
    var addWeek = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today.getTime() + (numberOfDaysForwardForNextTab * MILLIS_PER_DAY)), "GMT+1", "MM-dd-yy");
    var deleteWeek = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today.getTime() - (numberOfDaysBackwardForDeleteTab * MILLIS_PER_DAY)), "GMT+1", "MM-dd-yy"); 
  
    // Adds tab
    ss.duplicateActiveSheet(); //Copies current sheet
    ss.renameActiveSheet(addWeek); //Renames sheet to date from above
    ss.moveActiveSheet(1); //Moves sheet to the first position

    // Prepares tab (clears old content)
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(addWeek);
    sheet.getRange(rangeToClear).clearContent()
  
    // Deletes tab
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(deleteWeek));//Grabs tab to be deleted
    ss.deleteActiveSheet();   //Deletes tab
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One a Day Sheets

```
function oneADayForms(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shts = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => sh.getName().match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/)).map(sh => sh.getName());
  const dt = new Date();
  const td = new Date(dt.getFullYear(),dt.getMonth(),dt.getDate());
  const tdsh = Utilities.formatDate(td,SpreadsheetApp.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"yyyy-MM-dd");
  if(!~shts.indexOf(tdsh)) {
    ss.insertSheet(tdsh);
  } 
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(tdsh);
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, e.values.length).setValues([e.values]);
}
```

Comment: Hello, it appears that I am getting a syntax error when trying to save, stating there is a missing ')' after argument list on line 3, though I'm unsure where it should be.

Comment: Thanks for fixing, but it's now giving me a parse error: invalid regular expression line: 3.