# Automating Creation of New Spreadsheet from Form Daily

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, qualtrics

I am collecting new data everyday from a group of individuals in Google Forms.  This form is linked to a Google Sheet.  Every evening, a connected program (Qualtrics), accesses the Google Sheet and Imports the data to a contact list.  However, when it does this, it removes the Google Sheet from the Drive.
I'd like to create something in Google Apps Script that, every day, creates a new Google Sheet from the Form so that, later in the day, the connected program can see the new sheet.
I know it's possible to install a trigger from Google Apps Script, but I am not an engineer or that adept in much code.  Thank you so much.

I have looked at the following Google Apps Script and Stack Overflow articles:
[Google Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
[Similar (though not exact) Question with no answer](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/85724278/create-new-sheet-every-time-the-data-submitted-from-google-form?hl=en)
[Similar question in Stack Overflow, but focusing on keeping in the same sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74605811/how-to-set-up-a-google-sheet-to-automatically-create-new-tabs-sheets-for-google)

Comment: It does not have to remove the google sheet from the drive.  They are probably doing that because they know you will figure out how to build your own contact list sooner or later because it's probably not very hard probably less than 2 hours work.

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for the response!  I agree, they're doing it to prevent me from using their service to gather the contacts (which I'd like to avoid).  However, two hours of work assumes me having a level of skill I likely don't have. Do you have a recommendation as to where I could hire someone to do this?

Comment: I think any of the regular volunteers on this site would be quite capable of solving the issue,  Start with the [top users list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/topusers)

Comment: Thanks, @Cooper, that list does include you!  Do you have any interest?

Comment: @Cooper is right, it is better to fix the problem rather than use a band-aid. But, as someone who doesn't deserve to be a "top user", a less complicated &/or interim option might be to programmatically make a copy of the responses spreadsheet each day and let Qualtrics get the data from, and then delete, that _copy_ of the spreadsheet.